# NSXMLParser didEndElement and didStartElement is not being called

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser, saxparser

I want to parse the following info for my iPhone application but it is not working

```
<account>
  <account_list type="required">
          <test_account value="ABCD" />
  </account_list>
</account>

#define kAccount @"account"
#define kAccountList @"account_list"
#define kTestAccount @"test_account"
#define kAttValue @"value"
#define kAttType @"type"
```

Here is "didStartElement"

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{   


else if([elementName isEqualToString:kAccountList])
{
    if([[_elemsStack head] isEqualToString:kAccount])
    {
        _currentTestAccount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString* type = [attributeDict valueForKey:kAttrType];
        [_currentTestAccount addObject:type];
    }
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:kTestAccount])
{
    if([[_elemsStack head] isEqualToString:kAccountList])
    {
        NSString* value = [attributeDict valueForKey:kAttValue];
        [_currentTestAccount addObject:value];
    }
}
```

Here is "didFinishElement"

```
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:kAccountList])
    {
        if ([_elemsStack startsWith:kAccount, nil])
        {
        if (_currentTestAccount != nil)
        {
            _currentData._currentTestAccount = _currentTestAccount;
            _currentTestAccount = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help on this implementation,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you call the parsing. Did you set the delegate? If I remember correctly, some property needs to be strong (the NSXMLParser).

Comment: @Larme yes I set, actually when I set the breakpoint I can see the _currentTestAccount but with the 0 object , I think there is something wrong with my "didStartElement" and "didFinishElement" method